# Adding Windows 7 32 bit as dual boot option

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, multi-boot

A relative of mine has bought a new laptop this year on which windows 7 (64 bit) is installed. Aside some standard programs he uses on that laptop, he also has some software for his bike that needs to run. The developers of that program still don't support 64-bit systems and therefor I thought about making it dual boot, so he can still use the power of the 64-bit, and just for the bike program, he can initiate the 32-bit version.

My questions now are:

- What are the risks involved in this operation?
- What steps need to be taken to make this dual boot succesful?
- Any other ideas besides dual booting?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I might have forgotten/misphrased something. The software does run on 64-bit, but it cannot find the bike connected to the computer. So I think it's a matter drivers which aren't compatible with the 64-bit system. That's why I wanted to install the 32-bit windows so the drivers would work.

**Edit**

I've used virtualization, but couldn't get the bike to work. i suspect outdated software/drivers from the manufacturers side.

Comment: Won't the 32 bit application run? Does it show an error? Every 32 bit application for me has been able to run on a 64 bit machine

Comment: @SandeepBansal: Not every 32 bit application can run.  Notable, any 32 bit device driver, like the software to connect to hardware **won't run**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no need to reboot.

If the device on the bike uses a USB to connect, then my suggestion would be to use VirtualBox or Virtual PC to install a 32 bit version of Windows.

After installing the OS inside the VM, install the drivers.  Next plug in the device.  You might need to surpress Windows Update from looking for a driver.  Under either VirtualBox or VirtualPC, there is an option to **attach USB device**.  Your bike's device should show up.

BTW, this is the same method I use for my old scanner, which does not have 64 bit driver support.

Comment: Since sgmoore was -1'd I felt it appropriate to -1 this question.  Section 2d of the OEM license agreement (available through the menus at http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx ) states "You may use only one version at one time".  Thus, implementing THIS solution would be MORE EXPENSIVE than sgmoore's since you'd have to buy another Windows 7 Retail license rather than the anytime upgrade to Win7 Pro if using the Home edition.

Comment: @MultiverseIT: I must agree with your assessment. Upgrading editions is clearly a cheaper route.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Windows 7's Boot from VHD. It lets you install another copy of Windows 7 into a VHD (virtual hard disk) file and boot the PC from it.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd758779

Comment: +1: I have a Windows 7 Laptop and I boot Windows 7, Windows 8 Dev Preview, and Windows 8 Server - all run from VHDs and run quite nicely.  The procedure to install to a VHD is fairly simple but does require a little typing in a command prompt during setup to mount the VHD so Windows Setup sees it.  Further, because this would be "dual booting" it should not violate licensing (as I read and understand licensing) since you could still only run one copy of Windows at a time.  The obvious downside is that you have to reboot to switch versions.

Answer (score 0):

> Any other ideas besides dual booting?

Try XP Mode.

If you decide to install another operating system, you will need a separate drive or partition. You will also need another licence. Your Windows 7 licence does however allow you to use XP mode.

Comment: -1: Not every edition of Windows 7 allows XP mode. Only Professional, Ultimate, and Enterprise.

Comment: @surfasb. Good point. I keep forgetting about Windows Home.

Comment: Using XP mode would LIKELY be the most practical solution, however, it's not free and would cost about $90 (based on the last time I used it to upgrade from Win7 Home to Win7 Pro).

Comment: the operating system is still the standard Home which ships with most laptops, so I cannot use XP Mode.